# How to prevent TTP.sys remote code execution vulnerability in IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, iis-7

I deployed my asp.net 4.0 application into the windows server 2008 R2 Standard. The application working properly but the security team in our company reported the below issue.

> WebInspect has detected a critical HTTP.sys remote code execution vulnerability in IIS server. Identified as CVE-2015-1635, the vulnerability manifests itself on Microsoft windows-based servers that use unpatched HTTP kernel-mode driver, HTTP.sys when a web request with a malformed Range header is sent over HTTP. The vulnerability can enable attackers to achieve remote code execution on the target web server via a specially crafted HTTP request.

How to prevent this security Issue on the IIS server ?

Comment: Is there anything related to programming in this question?

Comment: This is not related to programming, This is related to security on IIS server over the HTTP requests.

Comment: [Patch your servers](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms15-034)

Comment: @user3089816 did you miss to read the [tour] and about what kind of questions to ask here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete details about this Issue.

1. This is a windows patching issue(If Microsoft update MS15-034 is not installed on the windows server 2008 R.
2. In order to fix this issue please follow the below steps
   a.  Please take the backup of our data before you proceed.
   b.  To permanently resolve this issue you must apply this patch called MS15-034, This patch is available through windows update. This needs to be done by the server Administrators or production Engineers(PE’s).
   c.  We can also resolve this issue temporarily by disabling the IIS kernel cache since it is enabled by default but this will effect system performance.